# Why do I get "cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte' when I try to generate a random color in C#?

Tags: c#

I was trying to generate a random color in C# today.

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
                                   randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
                                   randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
                                   randomGenerator.Next(1, 255));
```

But VS2012 keeps saying that Argument 1/2/3/4:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte'.

Moreover, I was trying to find `System.Drawing.Color`, but couldn't find it. Same for `System.Timer`.

Comment: ..following on from Mitch, `(byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255)`...

Comment: Did you try converting from int to byte? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Random.Next` returns an `int`, but `FromArgb` takes `byte`.

So you need to cast the ints to bytes:

```
randomColor = Color.FromArgb((byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
              (byte)randomGenerator.Next...`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just cast the random values to the type 'byte' that the method expects:

```
Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb((byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255), 
                                   (byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
                                   (byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255),
                                   (byte)randomGenerator.Next(1, 255));
```

Further, you probably don't see System.Drawing.Color because, I'm guessing, you're in a WPF app and you would need to add a reference to System.Drawing, but you should have a Timer object available under System.Timers.Timer.

Answer (score 0):

Because int has more range then byte so you need explicit type convertion

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any number to argb color with the following code:

```
        Color color;
        int num = 255;
        double d = 205.0 / (num + 256);

        int red = Math.Min((int)(d * 256), 255);
        int green = Math.Min((int)((d * 256 - red) * 256), 255);
        int blue = Math.Min((int)(((d * 256 - red) * 256 - green) * 256), 255);

        color = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
```

Comment: You answer does not focus on the question originally asked by user user2356729.